# HTML editor with DOM outline

Tags: osx, html, editor

I'm regularly doing web scraping using Python, and I tend do download the source of a URL (e.g. using `cURL`) and then examine the contents of the downloaded file.

I use TextMate for all editing, but going through unformatted HTML is rather masochistic. What would be ideal is a viewer that **parses the DOM** and presents it in a **structured way**, and optionally **reformats the HTML code.**

Below is a screenshot showing [Xmplify](http://xmplifyapp.com), a native macOS XML editor that does exactly that, but for XML files. If something like this existed for HTML files, it'd be perfect.

Another example, this time for JSON, is [Jayson](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jayson-visual-json-editor/id1189824719?mt=12).

[image: Xmplify]

Remarks:

- Why not use Xmplify for HTML source? Because not all HTML is well-formed and I don't want to make changes to the original code (that would "interfere" with scraping).
- I know that most browsers offer developer tools and have some/all of this functionality. However, as I'm doing scraping with `requests`, I need to use the HTML code without any JavaScript being run (and possibly modifying the DOM). And yes, I could turn off JavaScript in the browser, but I'd prefer not to.
- I don't need anything like validation, previewing, WYSIWYG, … My use case is web scraping, not web design.

So to reiterate, the requirements are:

- DOM outline
- HTML reformatting

Preferences:

- I would definitely prefer a native **Mac** app (no Java, Electron, …).
- If it only does what I need, even better (e.g. I'd prefer if it doesn't do *n* number of other things as well).

Thank you!